# Display user friendly message for json serialisation error

Tags: ios, swift

Iam working on an ios application which uses Alamofire for networking. Some times i get json serialization error. I need to display some user friendly messsage when this error comes. How can I do this by checking Nserror code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you first check the error != nil, then show your MSG.

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your response gives serialization error then you can get status `isFailure` You can display some custom message or can user `response.result.error` object.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseSwiftyJSON { (response) in
       if response.result.isSuccess {
              // Handle your json  
       } else {
          // display message Something went Wrong
       }
   }
```

Comment: If I am not wrong your answer is for server errors,  the problem she is having is  JSON serialization error, this error occurs when you try serialization your resonse from the wrong formate like the server is sending dictionary but you try to serialize your response for an array,

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check [AFError](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/AFError.swift).swift file to get familiar with possible values.

```
switch responseJson.result.error as? AFError{



                case .responseSerializationFailed(let reason)?:
                    switch reason {

                    case .inputDataNil:
                        break
                    case .inputDataNilOrZeroLength:
                        break
                    case .inputFileNil:
                        break
                    case .inputFileReadFailed(let at):
                        break
                    case .stringSerializationFailed(let encoding):
                        break
                    case .jsonSerializationFailed(let error): break

***////// DO What ever you want here //////////////////***


                    case .propertyListSerializationFailed(let error):
                        break
                    }

                case .some(.multipartEncodingFailed(let reason)):
                    break
                case .some(.responseValidationFailed(let reason)):
                    break
                case .some(.responseSerializationFailed(let reason)):
                    break
                case .none:
                    <#code#>
                case .some(.invalidURL(let url)):
                    <#code#>
                }
```